# Work with CORS in Angular

Tags: azure, cors

I work with Angular 6 and API from another site.

I've got this Error

```
Failed to load https://dashboard.revain.org/api/v1/projects?perPage=100&period=1d&page=1&sort=rank&direction=DESC: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://beta-rev.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Everything shows great with this expansion "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * "
But I need, that everyone looks what I see.

So I've googled and make web.config with this properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
      <!-- use utf-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html -->
      <!-- in the case of .html files; if you AJAX load html files (i.e. in angular) then remove these two lines. -->
      <remove fileExtension=".html"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".css"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".js"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".rss"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".xml"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".ico"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".webp"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".htc"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".vcf"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".torrent"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".cur"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".webapp"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But it shows the same error.

Comment: This is related to your back-end, not Angular, I'm going to remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to request a resource from another domain (dashboard.revain.org) outside the domain from which the first resource was served (beta-rev.azurewebsites.net). Read more about [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

To solve your issue you have to enable CORS somehwere on **revain.org** for your beta-rev.azurewebsites.net domain. You can't do that on your web app.

Comment: Can you give me advice, what exactly can help solve my problem. I should get accept from dashboard.revain.org or I need do smth with my beta-rev backend?

Comment: You have to enable CORS for your web app somewhere on dashboard.revain.org.

Comment: I've gone to azure and then go to dashboard.revain.org settings after that API -> CORS  and add domain beta-rev.azurewebsites.net now everything work. Thanks.

Comment: Why if i do the local request on Insomnia or Postman works, but on local Angular does not works. I don't understand

Comment: CORS is implemented by your browser.